# how can i add ultrasonic sensor to husky simulation in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, husky, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to permanently add sensors to husky and want to know the methodology generally for any sensor and if there special cases to deal with it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345063/how-can-i-add-ultrasonic-sensor-to-husky-simulation-in-gazebo?/) by [Ahmed Ezz](https://answers.ros.org/users/52065/ahmed-ezz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just add it to your URDF (and SDF if appropriate). If you have a husky URDF, hopefully there's another sensor in there you can use as a guide, else, look at turtlebot or other robot configurations for a guide.

Then it will come up every time with your custom URDF.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0